# Mute My App When Other Apps are Playing Music in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm writing an app that plays music. However, I'd like to make it so that my app's music pauses when other music is playing, such as music from iTunes. How would I accomplish this? Here's my code:

```
 var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ambler", ofType: "mp3")!)

    // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this I believe you are going to need to check if the music player is playing, here is how I would do that in Objective-C.

First `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` and add the library to your build phases.

```
- (BOOL)isPlaying
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
    if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

When initializing `musicPlayer` it may cause the music to stop, if so I would 
look into

`+ (MPMusicPlayerController *)applicationMusicPlayer`

Swift

```
func isPlaying() -> Bool {

    let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    if musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: How would I go about converting this to Swift?

Comment: @kriskendall99 If you know swift at all this shouldn't be hard, I've never written an application in Swift but I was able to do it, check the updated answer.